# fetch images from xcassets, language/encryption error?

Tags: ios, uiimage

I am having a bit of a problem fetching images in xcassets catalog when the asset names contain characters like å ä ö.

The problem is that I am setting a buttons image specified from a specific NSString. Unfortunately only buttons without åäö are loaded as button images:

```
NSString *temp = @"bondgård_icon_open"; 
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:temp] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  //never loaded

NSString *temp2 = @"djungel_icon_open"; 
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:temp2] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //loaded
```

I have searched the forum but not found anyone with similar problems. What am I missing?

Is there some place to set the encoding for asset names? I have checked JSON file for asset is UTF-8 so that seems to be ok.

Comment: Can you just load the images without the special characters in the names?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The easiest way to solve it would be to change the names to avoid these characters but the way the app is constructed, I need to have these characters... It worked fine on Xcode 4 (without xcassets) where I created the app but assets seem to be a great way to handle lots of images, and I have over 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that the string has to be decomposed before setting the image with a name containing å ä ö. Worked fine if I set the image after:

```
[temp decomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping]     
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:temp] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //loaded
```

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1235/_index.html for more info.